# Is there a way I can disable Typescript code analysis in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, version, typescript

The title says it all. I currently have the typescript 0.9 compiler installed on my system, but Intellij only supports the 0.8 language style (e.g. bool instead of boolean). Is there a way to disable it?

I have Idea Intellij 12.1.3.

Comment: You can turn inspections off (change the level of inspections to 'None'). This can be dome using Hector icon in the status bar. But unfortunately this is done at file level, there is no way to turn inspections off for all files at once

Comment: It works just fine. It would've been better to be able to configure it globally, but I'm surely glad there IS a way. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some settings for this - depending on whether you are seeing intentions or inspections. If you open settings and head for...

"Project Settings" and then "Inspections" and click "Reset to empty"

You can also hit the unhappy-face in the bottom-right corner and slide the inspection level between "None", "Syntax" and "Inspections".

You can also suppress specific issues using the red light-bulb icon. It will add a comment such as this:

```
//noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
```

This also gives you clues about the fact that TypeScript inspections are actually JavaScript inspections.

Or

"IDE Settings" and then "Intentions" and un-tick the boxes you don't want to run.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 12 only supports TypeScript 0.8.

You can download the EAP version for IntelliJ from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP where they added support for TypeScript 0.9 features.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the `dist/` folder in the Project window.  Click `Mark Directory As` -> `Excluded`.  This should clear it up without having to mess with inspection settings