# Angular 2 bootstrap function gives error "Argument type AppComponent is not assignable to parameter type Type"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea

Here is my first simple `Hello World` angular 2 app from [Angular 2 quick start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
@Component({
    selector: 'ng2-app',
    template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }


bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The application runs fine when I run with `npm start` but my IntelliJ IDE is showing error in the line with `bootstrap(AppComponent)`

> Argument type *AppComponent* is not assignable to parameter type *Type*

[image: Angular 2 typescript warning]

Looking at the `bootstrap` function declaration, `AppComponent` needs to extends `Type`.

```
export declare function bootstrap(appComponentType: Type, customProviders?: Array<any>): Promise<ComponentRef>;
```

My question is:

**Is it expected for Angular components to extend `Type`?**

Comment: Is this a newly updated version of IntelliJ within the last week? I ask because the most recent version of WebStorm has trouble with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ 15.0.2

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this, but to quiet it down for now you could write `bootstrap(<Type> AppComponent)`. Hopefully JetBrains gets it together soon.

Comment: I'm also using 15.0.2 and am experiencing similar trouble with component references inside `bootstrap`, as well as, with references inside directives and within the `@RouteConfig` section. I added `<any>` in front of the problematic references (e.g. `bootstrap(<any>App)` and `directives: [...COMMON_DIRECTIVES, <any>RouterOutlet]` and `@RouteConfig([{ path: '/', component: <any>HomeComponent, as: 'Home'}])`), which quieted things down for now.

Comment: @AaronJessen This solved my issue with directives. Is this an issue with phpstorm/webstorm or just a typescript issue?

Comment: @JasonSpick I can't yet say. I'm hoping it's a JetBrains thing that will be fixed in next release, although the current changelist for the Early Access Program (EAP) of IntelliJ 143.1653.2 does not yet mention it). FWIW, I'm using TypeScript 1.7.5 and a Webpack transpiler (meaning IntelliJ is **not** configured to compile TS automatically in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript: Enable TypeScript Compiler`). Also angular2-DefinitelyTyped community stub in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` is inactive (it throws errors with *some* ng2 `import` statements).

Comment: Looks like the latest update has this fixed.

Comment: @AaronJessen, thank you for pointing out what you are _not_ doing, because that inspired me to enable `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript: Enable TypeScript Compiler` which solved this problem for me. ...aah, just now see that this is exactly JockX's answer, so will vote that up. BTW, when I say it is solved for me, I mean I don't need either `<Type>` or `<any>` at all: the error/warning message for `bootstrap(AppComponent)` now simply goes away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, ***AppComponent is expected to extend Type***. So use the following:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, Type } from '@angular2/core';

@Component({
...
...
})
export class AppComponent extends Type {}
```

This will also follow the expected convention by ng2 for AppComponent (to be bootstrapped).

I am not sure why they didn't cover it in the ng2 tutorials, probably they might be targeting to simplify the initial learning, as it runs even without the **extends** part.

This works perfectly fine in WebStorm/IntelliJ.

**Edit:** Alternate solution is to update to Webstorm v2016.2 (which is stable at the time of this comment).

Comment: Some reference for "AppComponent is expected to extend Type" would be great. [Official angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) makes no mention of that.

Comment: This was a posted a while back. Still your concern is valid. Please go to following links, I wished to paste an image, but I hope that isn't possible in comment  
1. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/PlatformRef-class.html. Go to bootstrapModule definition, the type of first argument is Type<M> which I can see is generic now  
2. When you install ng-2 using npm, navigate to node_modules\@angular\core\src\application_ref.d.ts: line 122. The similar definition exists.
Again I stress angular-2 has changed a lot since last we saw it. My comment might get outdated after some time.

Answer (score 52):

I stumbled on this in Intellij 2016.1.2, with the Angular quickstart demo. Setting the following options in IDE helped:

[image]

Comment: thanks, why it effect on inspections of code? Do not want continuously compile code by IDE

Comment: Worked perfectly on my PhpStorm

Comment: Sorry but this answer is not reliable. Npm is watching for TypeScript changes and compiling TS to JS. So activating this option, TS gets compiled 2 times(from IDE and from npm).

Comment: @Mick, you wouldn't use this option with `tsc -w` command. You would want to use one or the other not both.

Comment: noice, worked like a charm. I'm not automatically compiling my TS so I didn't realize this was the problem

Comment: gorgeous hand drawn circle. have a cheap upvote. also it solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 14):

adding comment / annotation like shown below solves the problem

```
//noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: Here is good answer for your question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189062/is-there-a-way-i-can-disable-typescript-code-analysis-in-intellij)

Answer (score 11):

The above answer did not work for me. I was able to fix it by doing what was recommended in the comments above.

```
bootstrap(<any>AppComponent);
```

I am using Intellij 14.1.5

Answer (score 1):

IMO changing the code all over just so that WebStorm / IntelliJ will not complain is not a viable solution.
Since I have a separate bundling / compiling process I instead disabled IntelliJ's ops on typescript:
Settings->Languages->Typescript - uncheck the options there.
If that is already the case for you than you can try checking the options, applying and then unchecking again.

You can see this is still a bit buggy. For example after I have done some class renaming using the IDE (SHIFT + F6) the errors returned. Repeating the above removed them again.

Using IntelliJ 15.0.2

Comment: Note that if you need to enable the typescript compiler than I'd recommend setting a specific path at "Use output path" field.

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm 2016.1.3 the solution above works for me

Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> TypeScript:
Enable TypeScript,
Use tsconfig.json

PS: This is the same solution as described before for previous Webstorm version (2016.1.3)

Comment: This answer is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/37631635/1433665

Answer (score 1):

This error introducing due to TypeScript compiler is not enabled in your IDE. you need to enable TypeScript compiler.

Enable Typescript compiler in Webstorm:

go to Webstorm menu(upper left menu) => Preferences menu => Languages & Frameworks => click on TypeScript =>
Enable Typescript compiler(enable checkbox) => enable Use tsconfig.json option => click Ok button and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the new angular2 router I had to do ..

```
bootstrap(AppComponent [
    <any>APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]).catch((err:any) => console.error(err));
```

NOTE any is used on APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS not AppComponent.

Answer (score -2):

`//noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes`
Worked for me in WebStorm.

Also I've opened my project in IntelIJ instead and there was no error.