# Angular 2 Router Module function gives error "Argument type ... is not assignable to parameter type Routes"

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I was creating an Angular 2 App with some simple routing:

*(main.module.ts)*

```
import { routes } from './main.routes';
/* Other imports */
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HomeModule,
        TestModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes) // imported from file below
    ],
    declarations: [MainComponent, SidebarComponent],
    exports: [MainComponent, SidebarComponent]
})
```

*(main.routes.ts)*

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
/* Other imports */
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'test', component: TestComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

The application runs fine when I type npm start but my IntelliJ IDE is showing error in the line with `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

> Argument type {path: string, component: MainComponent, children: {path: string, component: HomeComponent}|{path: string, component: TestComponent}[]}[] is not assignable to parameter Routes

[image]

### I've also tried:

`export const routes: Routes = ]` *instead of* `export const routes = [`

After searching, I'm unable to find a reason or an alternative to implement it without error.

Comment: when you use `export const routes: Routes`, if you double-click on the type `Routes`, it should take you to the type definition. What does the definition look like, and which file is it in?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: <any>MainComponent },
   { path: '', component: <any>MainComponent }
];
```

I found it by looking through the definition of Route[]. Ended up finding out the conflict was only in `component: MainComponent`. Happens that the interface `Route` is expecting it to be `component?: Type<any>;`. At the begging I though it wasn't a Type problem (not duplicate). But, **I concluded it was expected to extend Type**.

Credits: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366797/angular-2-bootstrap-function-gives-error-argument-type-appcomponent-is-not-assi) and thanks to @BeetleJuice